# UIWebView opening URL after google search makes app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I don't know the reason but as soon as i get from a `UITextField` some data, like "Facebook", i call this code

```
- (IBAction)searchForAddress:(id)sender
{
    [self loadRequestFromAddressField:_addressField];
}

- (void)loadRequestFromAddressField:(id)addressField
{
    NSString *urlString = [addressField text];
    [self loadRequestFromString:urlString];
}

- (void)loadRequestFromString:(NSString*)urlString
{
    NSString *composedUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",urlString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:composedUrlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

Now the UIWebView loads correctly giving me the result of the google search, the problem is that when i try to enter some link it crashes giving me this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WeBViewController searchURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f38540'
```

What could be the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your `WeBViewController` have methode name `searchURL` 
it is very basic error.

It means you are calling method on instance of WeBViewController which is not implemented in it.
If you are still unable to fix this issue you can paste your code in question so we can take look at it.

Comment: i don't have any method called searchURL! The fact is that if i change the `composedUrlString`setting it to be `http://www.%@.com`it gives me no error loading the URL perfectly. Could the problem be with the google search `http://www.google.com/search?q=%@`?